# Response in browser after android post

Tags: php, post, http-post

My android app sends photos by HTTP Post. I want simply show newest image in browser window. Like webcam. I'm a php newbie.

I want after getting image by post metod show photo in browser. This code sends response to android Logcat and saves image on server. 
I can't get on browser window information "The file " .  $strPath . " has been uploaded.". So i don't know when i should show a photo.

```
<?php

    $objFile = & $_FILES["file"];
    $strPath = basename( $objFile["name"] );
    if( move_uploaded_file( $objFile["tmp_name"], $strPath ) ) {
        echo "The file " .  $strPath . " has been uploaded.";
        } else {
        echo "There was an error, please try again!";
    }
?>
```

Comment: You caanot "push" something into a client side browser. The browser has to make a request to "fetch" something. So you might start a new browser instance on the client side from within the android app and lauch it with a url pointing to a script delivering the previously uploaded picture.

Comment: 1) There is absolutely no reason to reference `$_FILES["file"]`. You are misusing references. 2) The `$liczba` variable is never defined and will give you an error. Turn on errors so you can fix your own code. 3) You are allowing anything and everything to be uploaded, which is majorly stupid. 4) You should be a lot more specific in where you move the uploaded file to. Create a dedicated folder for the files and then move them there.

Comment: Sorry, $liczba is a mistake after debugging.

Can I show newest photo only after client click refresh? How will client know witch image will be newest?